# Upload file to server without browse using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, upload

I need to upload a file from client side(Backbone) to server side(Zoho) without opening any browse file dialog box.
**What I need to do** : Email with its attached file would be sent to any person.
I am passing SMTP settings and other parameters to client as request parameters BUT how can I upload .csv file (which includes my data) to server without asking user to browse the file.

Kindly guide me..

Comment: How else do you expect to know where the file is? Is it always in a specific place? Can you access the file from there machine? I doubt you can access it. The file dialog passes the file to the browser so you have access, and so you don't need to go snooping around a persons PC.

Comment: There are some trojen programs :)

Comment: @Nunners:I have .csv file in my folder.

Comment: its a security issue, you cannot upload file into server without user's approval or interaction.

Comment: Is it possible to upload a file without browsing it when server allow me to upload it by writing some permissions and parameters in its headers

Comment: Browser code is sand-boxed, and you can't access anything without user interaction. You can get rid of the browse dialog if the user [drags a file onto your page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/), but you can't just grab a file from the user's computer. As mentioned, this is a security feature, and a good one at that.

Comment: ok so it seems that its not possible to do it in the way I want.I would better opt the method of sendind whole data to server instead of file.